# Конструкторы и операторы копирования

Tags: конструктор, c++

Могу ли я записать конструктор копирования через оператор присваивания?
Например вот так:

```
A::A(const A * a) {
    *this = a;
}

A &A::operator=(const A * a) {
    delete str;
    str = new char[strlen(a->str)+1];
    strcpy(str, a->str);
    return *this;

}
```

Еще хочется уточнить, правильно ли если я делаю A * a в примере выше, потому примеры с разных сайтов A & a. C этого всплывает вопрос, что должен возвращать оператор присваивание:

```
A &A::operator=(const A * a)
```

или

```
A * A::operator=(const A * a)
```

Вообщем правильный ли мой код выше?

Объект класса создается так A * a = new A();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конструктор копирования можно написать через оператор присваивания, не вопрос.

Только то, что вы пишете — это не конструктор копирования и не оператор присваивания. Для них аргументом является экземпляр класса, а не указатель на него.

Код неправильный ещё и по другой причине: вы не учитываете случай [копирования объекта в себя](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/self-assignment-why.html).

Сигнатура конструктора копирования обязана быть `A(A& a)` или `A(const A& a)` (есть ещё немного экзотических возможностей, вот [документация](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor)), всё остальное, в частности, то, что у вас — не конструктор копирования.

Сигнатура оператора копирующего присваивания (а начиная с C++11 возможен и перемещающий) обязана быть `A& operator= (A a)` или `A& operator= (const A& a)` ([документация](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_operator)), всё остальное — не оператор копирующего присваивания.

В частности, у вас просто конструктор из стороннего типа, и оператор присваивания значения стороннего типа. Указатель на `A` для `A` — сторонний тип.

Comment: @VladD посмотрите пожалуйста следующий код http://pastebin.com/xQN0Dpk4 Он корректно написан. (не обращайте внимания на такую иерархию)

Comment: @andrey3: о, вот это намного лучше выглядит. только вместо

    B::operator(*b); //здесь через * правильно? по другому вроде бы не работает.

надо наверное

    B::operator=(*b);

да? И это не «через `*`», это разыменование указателя. (Ну да, пишетеся «через `*`», но звучит ужасно наивно.)

Comment: @VladD спасибо большое. А то через & раньше не работало, поэтому я написал через *. А стал пересматривать примеры - через * не нашел. Вот и решил спросить.

Comment: @andrey3: Ну вы всё же разберитесь, что означает `*` и `&`, чтобы могли сами до написания кода понимать, что будет работать, а что нет.

Comment: @VladD еще раз побеспокою. Оператор копирования не хочет вызываться (смотрю в отладчике) A * a = new A("stroka"); A * a1 = new A("sotroka2"); a = a1; А вот если записать без динамического выделения памяти, то все работает. Почему?

Comment: И не вызовется. Вы ж не объект копируете, а указатель на него.

В вашей записи `a` и `a1` — указатели.

Вот, почитайте про указатели: http://ericlippert.com/2014/05/12/what-are-the-fundamental-rules-of-pointers/

Comment: @VladD да заработало... но с этого всего теперь появился еще один вопрос http://pastebin.com/8Z1YrnqG

Comment: @andrey3: Смотрите:

1. Дескрипторы файлов вовсе не копируемы. Поэтому если в классе есть дескриптор файла, его копировать нельзя. (Почему? Потому что если вы закроете в одном объекте файл, в другом он тоже окажется закрыт, хотя другой объект об этом не будет знать.)
2. Нет, там копируются указатели. Там вообще нету двух объектов, это указатели на **один и тот же объект**.